# How do I only select the "tr" element that was clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an HTML table with different rows (TR) and when I click on one row the background color changes (if it blank it becomes blu and if it blue it becomes white).

How can I exclude from this onclick event the TR that have the TD with the class `EXPANDREDUCE`?

My code is the following but it doesn't work because in this way it works on each TR i click but I need to check if in the TR that I clicked there is one or more TD with the CLASS `EXPANDREDUCE` and if yes i don't need to do anything:

```
function rowHighlight() {
  $("TR").click(function() {
    try {
      $(this).parent().prev()[0].tagName;
      HighLightTR(this);
    } catch (err) {}
  });
}
```

Answer (score 6):

By using the [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) property, like this:

```
$("tr").on("click", function(event) {
  var tr = $(event.target);
});
```

**NOTE:** To check to see if it has the class `EXPANDREDUCE`, change your selector to `"tr.EXPANDREDUCE"`.

Good luck.

Comment: because I wrote i this way just to make a test :   var TR = $(event.target);
if($('TR').find('TD[CLASS*="EXPANDREDUCE"]').length>0 ){
 alert('ole');
} but it dosn't work properly because the alert works always

Comment: It seems that if I HAVE only one TD WITH THIS CLASS in the page it doesn't matter on which row I click i see always the alert

Comment: @Dana You're not supposed to capitalize selectors like that also, you're supposed to add the `EXPANDREDUCE` class to the `td` selector.

Comment: i'M SORRY BUT i DON'T UNDERSTAND well because i never work with javascript!.. if I print  var tr = $(event.target); I have object object as results

Comment: @Dana You code doesn't work because you're searching for a child `<td>` that has a class attribute that contains the word `EXPANDREDUCE`, when you're supposed to be doing is using the [`hasClass`](https://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) function, like this: `$(event.target).hasClass("EXPANDREDUCE")`.

Comment: is not possible to have the value contained in the TR..? It should be the complete TR that I CLICKED.. in this way I can check if i have one td with the class i'msearchinf for..

Comment: @Dana in order to print an object's keys/values use the [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) functions.

Comment: @Dana If you want the `tr` element's child `td` to be the click target, then change your selector to `"td.EXPANDREDUCE"`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example:

```js
$(function() {
  $("thead tr").addClass("background");
  $("tbody tr:even").addClass("even");
  $("tbody tr:odd").addClass("odd");
  $("tbody input:checkbox:checked").parent().parent().addClass("sel");

  $("tbody tr").click(function(e) {
    var flag = $(this).hasClass("sel");
    if (flag) {
      $(this).removeClass("sel");
    } else {
      $(this).addClass("sel");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 400px;
  border: 2px solid #999;
  text-align: center;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table td, table th {
  border: 2px solid #999;
  height: 25px;
}

.background {
  background-color: #CCC;
}

.even {
  background-color: #FFE7BA;
}

.odd {
  background-color: #FFF0F5;
}

.sel {
  background-color: #FFFF00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>title</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code! But in this example you put the same behaviour to each TD. I want to see if it possible if you can set to the TD with the value 2 a class like 'pippo' and to make that when you click on the cell with the value 2 nothing changes

Comment: I have exactly the same situation, but the difference is that when you find a specific class in one TD the complete TR doesn't have to change the color when you click on